# I cannot load leaflets maps in flutter webview through local html file

Tags: flutter, leaflet, android-webview

I'm using flutter official webview plugin and I wrote all the permission required for flutter to use the internet in androidManifest as give below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and flutter code as follows:

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  late WebViewController _wvc;
  String filePath = 'assets/htmls/extreme_windspeed.html';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Weather Forecast Windspeed',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: WebView(
          // initialUrl: 'assets/htmls/extreme_windspeed.html',
          initialUrl:
              'https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController wvc) {
            _wvc = wvc;
            _loadHtmlFromAssets();
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text("Click"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the initial url like giving path. Get your local files content to a string then pass it like below;

```
 child: WebView(
          // initialUrl: 
          initialUrl:
    Uri.dataFromString(yourhtmlstring, mimeType: 'text/html').toString()
```

Comment: Yea, sorry that wasn't supposed to be there, I'm using this '_loadHtmlFromAssets();' webcontroller function to do exactly what you're saying.

Comment: Do you want to navigate another screen when webview created?

Comment: No, initially I'm giving an empty string to initialUrl when webview loads I'm passing my local html file as you suggested in the above comment.

Comment: please share _loadHtmlFromAssets(); function

Comment: `_loadHtmlFromAssets() async {`
    `String fileHtmlContent = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);`
    `_wvc.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContent,`
            `mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))`
        `.toString());`
  `}`

Comment: Never mind I understood the problem, I was trying to make a http call which flutter dosen't allow by default.

Comment: Yes you need to navigate to url

Comment: yes, I decalred that in the filePath variable.